# Copy text of a specific tag within multiple tags to clipboard using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to copy input of a specific tag without having to make an input field to my clipboard using JavaScript

JavaScript and HTML

```js
function copy(input){
  
}
```

```html
<p>Text To Copy = hi <button type="button" onclick="copy('hi')">click to copy</button></p>
```

Comment: No, cause I don't want to create a textarea and all solutions there are by creating a textarea "I Think"

Comment: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)` does not use a text area. The [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) is the modern approach for interacting with the clipboard. This is described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function copy_text_fun() {
    //getting text from P tag
    var copyText = document.getElementById("copy_txt");  
    // creating textarea of html
    var input = document.createElement("textarea");
    //adding p tag text to textarea 
    input.value = copyText.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    // removing textarea after copy
    input.remove();
    alert(input.value);
}
```

```html
<p id="copy_txt">hi</p>
<button  onclick="copy_text_fun()">Copy</button>
```

here is with the paragraph tag,

Comment: Problem with this is that `document.execCommand("Copy");` is now decapitated!

Answer (score 8):

You can use `navigator.clipboard.writeText` to copy the text to clipboard.

```js
function copy(input) {
  if (navigator.clipboard) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(input).then(() => {
      console.log('Copied to clipboard successfully.');
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('Failed to copy the text to clipboard.', err);
    });
  } else if (window.clipboardData) {
    window.clipboardData.setData("Text", input);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Text To Copy = hi <button type="button" onclick="copy('hi')">click to copy</button></p>
```

Comment: it seems your code not working

Comment: On which browser are you testing? @CodeBug

Comment: chrome Version 84.0.4147.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Then it should work!!!

Comment: nope, it's not working tried with incognito too.

Comment: ya it's not working bro

Comment: This works now, thanks very much, I'll tip you a tipple till the next update!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this. Maybe it will work for you.

```js
 function myFunction() {
      /* Get the text field */
      var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
    
      /* Select the text field */
      copyText.select();
      copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); /*For mobile devices*/
    
      /* Copy the text inside the text field */
      document.execCommand("copy");
    
      /* Alert the copied text */
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
    }
```

```html
 <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i don't want it to be a input area that i wanna copy hope you understand

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? please ellaborate

Comment: See I have a flask back-end so i pass a var into code that i don't want to get edited So I want to copy that variable to clipboard without making any changes to it, here you can change the text

Comment: What I understand is you want to copy the value inside the variable? am I right? if possible please some actual code.